# Нахождение числа бинарным поиском - вычисление максимального и минимального количества операций

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Добрый день,

Хочется понять как высчитать минимальное и максимальное количество операций для нахождения произвольного числа в определенном промежутке значений.
Код для примера (C#):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int min = 2047;
            int max = 4096;
            int val = min;
            int counter = 0;                
            int i = r.Next(2047, 4096);                
            while(true)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("--> "+val);
               if(i == val) break;                    
               val = (max-min)/2 + min;                    
               if(i>val) {
                   min = val;
               }
               else if(i<val) {
                   max = val;
               }                    
               counter++;
            }                
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nThe calculated i is: "+val+", but i is: "+i+", done in "+counter+" counts.\n\n\n\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

В данном примере я вижу, что максимальное количество операций для нахождения числа в промежутке между 2047 и 4096 - это 11 (эмпирически, основано на 10000 запусках).
Как это посчетать без запуска? Где можно почитать теоритическое обьяснение?

Спасибо!

Comment: минимальное количество операций - 1, есть не нулевая вероятность сразу попасть в нужное число. Почитать теорию можно у Кормена "Алгоритмы, построение и анализ" остальное есть в ответе ниже

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так как Вы с каждой операцией отсекаете половину возможных чисел, то количество операций будет равно log(n, 2) (логарифм от n по основанию 2), где n - разница между максимом и минимумом

Comment: n - число элементов в массиве, по которому выполняем поиск. Максимум и минимум в общем случае ни при чем. Хотя если нужно "угадать" число из диапазона, то да, разница между границами диапазона